# AngularJS 1.4 - how to bind value between parent and child directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives which both have an isolated scope. I would like to require the parent directive in my child directive, and then be able to watch if a scope variable of the parent changes. I don't want to modify the variable in the child, I just want to be able to read it.

I want to be able to add different children which both have access to the list, but I don't want to have to bind the list to every child. What is missing in the example below, is a way to watch the list which gets bound to the parent. I am able to pass the original list in, but as soon as it updates, the child will have an outdated model.

Parent directive:

```
  angular
      .module('app.parent', [])
      .directive('parent', parent);

      function parent() {
          var directive =  {
              restrict: 'EA',
              transclude: true,
              template: '<div>parent <pre>{{vm.list}}</pre><ng-transclude></ng-transclude> </div>',
              scope: true,
              controller: ParentController,
              controllerAs: 'vm',
              bindToController: {
                  config: "=",
                  list: "="
              }
          };

          return directive;

      function ParentController() {
          var vm = this;
      }
  }
```

child directive:

```
angular
      .module('app.parent.child', ['app.parent'])
      .directive('child', child);

      function child() {
          var directive =  {
              restrict: 'EA',
              require: ['^^parent', '^child'],
              template: '<div>child<pre>{{vm.list}}</pre></div>',
              scope: true,
              controller: ChildController,
              link: linkFunc,
              controllerAs: 'vm',
              bindToController: {
                  config: "="
              }
          };

          return directive;

      function ChildController() {
          var vm = this;
      }

      function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
          var parentController = ctrls[0];
          var vm = ctrls[1];
          vm.list = parentController.list;
      }
  }
```

I have made a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMAZFHGfZmMGiYLhjSI1?p=preview) with the code above. I am looking for a nice pattern to solve the issue I am having. Both directives will have their own unique config object passed in with configurations specific to the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a watcher on the child directive's scope object, but rather than watching a scope item, you can pass in a function as the first parameter to `$watch()` and simply return a value/object that you would like to watch.

So for instance inside your child directive's `linkFunc()`

```
scope.$watch(function() {
        return parentController.list;
    }, function(newList) {
        vm.list = newList;
    });
```

Modified your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/6WzT8PQJRH1b5KuU0twn?p=preview

Comment: This works, thanks! I was already looking into putting the shared code into a service/provider. This is a lot easier for now!

Comment: @Joe Pontani, i'm binding one textbox on md-dialog which taking data from parent to child, now i  want to change same using text to hcild to parent. how can i do that? http://codepen.io/DevVersion/pen/wGOPgz?editors=1010